# buildozer: command not found

Tags: command-line, 18.04, kivy

So far I have run the following commands in terminal. (Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit):

```
cd ~/Documents/python
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python2.7 python2.7-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-8-jdk unzip ant ccache autoconf libtool
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev
pip3 install --upgrade cython virtualenv
pip3 install --user --upgrade buildozer
buildozer init
```

But then I get

`buildozer: command not found`

Why does this not work? I read on a similar question that the problem was resolved due to some dependencies not being installed, but I think I have installed all the dependencies I could find that were recommended.

Thanks

Comment: Add $HOME/.local/bin to your path.

Comment: Is this standard Ubuntu, or something else?

Comment: @heynnema I have downloaded Virtual box and am using a virtual version of Ubuntu on a Windows PC.

Comment: @ajgringo619 How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# add the following line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
```

- from https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: I read that webpage but somehow missed that instruction (perhaps I saw the `#` and thought it was a comment). But this worked for me, so thanks!